# Retirar letras de input, utilizando Javascript e expressão regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu tenho um campo input que recebe um valor. Eu gostaria de retirar letras e caracteres especiais do valor desse input, fazendo restar apenas números.
Acredito que seria mais fácil utilizar um replace com um expressão regular, mas não estou conseguindo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Eu tentei assim:

```
valor.replace(/\d|,/g, "");
```

Só que não faz nada.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

minha sugestao seria de você utilizar mascaras em JQuery, que facilitaria muito sua vida. Creio que se vc seguir o link abaixo poderá ter sucesso.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Qualquer dúvida, basta falar =D

Abraços,

Answer (score 1):

Você pode configurar para a tag  aceitar apenas números, conforme abaixo:

```
<input type="number"/>
```

Caso queira algo mais "seguro", você ainda pode fazer uma função que verifica caractere por caractere, enquanto o usuário digita. Por exemplo:

```js
function allowOnlyNumbers(e) {
    var tecla = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
    if ((tecla > 47 && tecla < 58)) return true;
    else {
        if (tecla == 8 || tecla == 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
};
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" onkeypress="return allowOnlyNumbers(event)"/>
```

Dessa forma, mesmo se o usuário apagar o tipo do input, ainda não conseguirá digitar letras ou caracteres especiais.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
Converte caracteres full width (zenkaku) para o half width (hankaku) 
O zenkaku são caracteres disponíveis nos conjuntos de caracteres japoneses.
Exemplo, １２３４５６７８９０ são números, porém, a expressão regular [^0-9\.] não os reconhece como números. Caso queira prover suporte a esse tipo de entrada, utilize o conversor da função ZenkakuToHankaku().
*/
function ZenkakuToHankaku(str) {
return str.replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g,function(s){return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0)-0xFEE0)});
}

/*
Remove tudo que não for número
*/
function NumberOnly(str) {
return ZenkakuToHankaku(str).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
}

/*
string para teste
*/
str = '123abc１２３文字 éã456';

/*
mostra o resultado no console (pressione CTRL+SHIFT+I no chrome)
*/
console.log(str = NumberOnly(str));

/*
teste, exibe o resultado no corpo html
*/
document.write(str);
```